# apache access log grew smaller

Tags: linux, attacks, webserver, apache

I used this command twice in the same day:

```
grep'21/Aug/2017:'/var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -
k2nr | uniq -c |wc -l
```

and first time it returned a number bigger than the second time. And those were not crazy numbers,less than a hundred. Same thing happened when there is no  `uniq -c` in the command. And after I noticed that, I checked my `/var/log/auth.log`,there is only less than ten entry all from myself within the hour. Command `history` gave nothing out of order. I wonder is there something I don't understand about logging or is my server compromised?

Comment: Before you start asking about compromise, reduce your search to the bare minimum so that you rule out all the potential conflicts between the various commands you are piping through. Has the actual line count been reduced? Try omitting the sort, for instance

Comment: You can also examine which lines are missing/different between your output and the original data. If any, report them here.

Comment: Try this:
grep'21/Aug/2017:'/var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -
k2nr | uniq -c > out1.txt. Do the same for the earlier log and take a diff of the 2.

Comment: Perhaps the logs were rotated? Many systems have `logrotate` set up to automatically rotate and compress logs after a certain time or when they reach a certain size.

Comment: @schroeder I don't see how there can be conflict. If no entry was lost , the number can't decrease.right?

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't know where the 'earlier' log is, if it is still there. I think Androl is right. I have to actually take a look at how these logs are maintained.

Comment: It's because of the `logrotate`.My ignorance,but thanks for all the help.